# how to make any variable entered lowered case

Tags: bash, shell, lowercase

if I asking for a username
I have this in the file

```
read -p 'enter username: ' username
```

what can I add to make sure it comes out lowercased?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
username="${username,,}"
```

to convert every character to lower case.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.